# xml data scraping more advanced than me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, html

Thanks for coming and understand I am new to this. So what seems easy to some is new to me.

I did some research on how to use javascript and/or php to pull data from an .xml file. I also can pull this .xml data into a mobile app using html5 canvas ( Construct 2 )

My issue is not related to nodes per se, But then again it is.

As it is easier if the node had text like this one.

```
<item>Hi There</item>
```

instead of subnodes like the one I wish to scrape.

```
<item game="powerball" nextjp="$67 Million" nextdd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnum="20-33-36-47-52 PB12 X3" windd="Saturday, August 6, 2016" myflv="widget_pb.flv" winnumNM="20-33-36-47-52 PB12" name="POWERBALL">
```

I wish to break down the node  so that it reads

```
Game
Next Jackpot
Next drawing
Winning Numbers
Game Played Date
```

It would have been easy for me if I could find an xml that already had the Nodes for each instead of all them inside one node. So with that said I don't need a full detailed script demo, I just need a basic overview of how it is done to get the subnode data. Thanks Jeremy C.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the insight, I will chat him up. But while I wait for a response, What is your take on this issue?

Comment: Hello @Iceman, Thanks for stopping by, Do you have any ideas? on how this is done? is it like item.game.text or am I way off base. As most coding has been quite straight forward. So it can't be to hard to understand once you get the basics.

Comment: how are you parsing xml in php, if that is infact what u r doing?

Comment: Hello @Iceman, I have a Javascript that pulls node data from an external url .xml file. It is quite simple. but no documentation on subnodes

Comment: cud u add the link to ur xml?

Comment: http://www.flalottery.com/video/en/theWinningNumber.xml

Comment: So with a little more digging I think it is something like find("item").attr("game").text and so forth. I am I getting hotter?

Comment: i'll write an answer. give me another 2 minutes

Comment: Hello @PeterKA I se you love my grammar. thanks for stopping by.

Comment: have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I've loaded the entire XML from a string. In real case, you'll need to probably pull it using ajax.

Note: the URL you added in comments from which I got this xml from doesnt have 'Allow * Origin Header" so, ajax from there will create a CORS error.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"><channel><title>Florida Lottery Winning Numbers</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com</link><description>Florida Lottery winning number drawing results for  FLORIDA LOTTO, MEGA MILLIONS, POWERBALL, LUCKY MONEY, FANTASY 5, Midday and Evening PICK 2, PICK3, PICK 4 and PICK 5</description><item game="powerball" nextjp="$67 Million" nextdd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnum="20-33-36-47-52 PB12 X3" windd="Saturday, August 6, 2016" myflv="widget_pb.flv" winnumNM="20-33-36-47-52 PB12" name="POWERBALL"><title>POWERBALL Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/powerball.do</link><description>POWERBALL winning numbers are 20-33-36-47-52 PB12 X3 for 08/06/2016 and the next estimated Jackpot is $67 Million for 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/powerball.do</guid></item><item game="lotto" nextjp="$12 Million" nextdd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnum="1-22-27-40-42-53 X3" windd="Saturday, August 6, 2016" myflv="widget_l6.flv" name="FLORIDA LOTTO"><title>FLORIDA LOTTO Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/lotto.do</link><description>FLORIDA LOTTO with Xtra winning numbers are 1-22-27-40-42-53 X3 for 08/06/2016 and the next Jackpot is $12 Million for 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/lotto.do</guid></item><item game="fan5" winnum="3-23-25-33-34" windd="Tuesday, August 9, 2016" myflv="widget_f5.flv" name="FANTASY 5"><title>FANTASY 5 Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/fantasy5.do</link><description>FANTASY 5 winning numbers are 3-23-25-33-34 for 08/09/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/fantasy5.do</guid></item><item game="pick5" winnumm="6-7-9-1-9" midd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnume="4-7-1-9-1" eved="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" myflvm="NA" myflve="NA" name="PICK 5"><title>PICK 5 Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/pick5.do</link><description>PICK 5 winning numbers are 6-7-9-1-9 for Midday 08/10/2016 and  4-7-1-9-1 for Evening 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/pick5.do</guid></item><item game="pick4" winnumm="3-6-4-7" midd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnume="7-1-1-7" eved="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" myflvm="widget_p4_midd.flv" myflve="widget_p4_eved.flv" name="PICK 4"><title>PICK 4 Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/pick4.do</link><description>PICK 4 winning numbers are 3-6-4-7 for Midday 08/10/2016 and  7-1-1-7 for Evening 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/pick4.do</guid></item><item game="pick3" winnumm="3-5-0" midd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnume="2-4-8" eved="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" myflvm="widget_c3_midd.flv" myflve="widget_c3_eved.flv" name="PICK 3"><title>PICK 3 Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/pick3.do</link><description>PICK 3 winning numbers are 3-5-0 for Midday 08/10/2016 and  2-4-8 for Evening 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/pick3.do</guid></item><item game="pick2" winnumm="9-6" midd="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" winnume="7-7" eved="Wednesday, August 10, 2016" myflvm="NA" myflve="NA" name="PICK 2"><title>PICK 2 Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/pick2.do</link><description>PICK 2 winning numbers are 9-6 for Midday 08/10/2016 and  7-7 for Evening 08/10/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/pick2.do</guid></item><item game="megamillions" nextjp="$45 Million" nextdd="Friday, August 12, 2016" winnum="12-19-20-44-66 MM1 X5" windd="Tuesday, August 9, 2016" name="MEGA MILLIONS"><title>MEGA MILLIONS Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/megaMillions.do</link><description>MEGA MILLIONS winning numbers are 12-19-20-44-66 MM1 X5 for 08/09/2016 and the next estimated Jackpot is $45 Million for 08/12/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/megaMillions.do</guid></item><item game="lucky" nextjp="$700,000" nextdd="Friday, August 12, 2016" winnum="1-11-27-39 LB3" windd="Tuesday, August 9, 2016" myflv="widget_lucky.flv" name="LUCKY MONEY"><title>LUCKY MONEY Drawing Results</title><link>http://www.flalottery.com/luckyMoney.do</link><description>LUCKY MONEY winning numbers are 1-11-27-39 LB3 for 08/09/2016 and the next Jackpot is $700,000 for 08/12/2016</description><pubDate>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 22:11:46 EST</pubDate><guid>http://www.flalottery.com/luckyMoney.do</guid></item></channel></rss>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc),
  $data = $xml.find("item");
var res = "";
$data.each(function() {
  var str = "<tr>";
  str += "<td>" + ($(this).attr('game')) + "</td>";
  str += "<td>" + ($(this).attr('nextjp')) + "</td>";
  str += "<td>" + ($(this).attr('nextdd')) + "</td>";
  str += "<td>" + ($(this).attr('winnum')) + "</td>";
  str += "<td>" + ($(this).attr('windd')) + "</td>";
  str += "</tr>";
  res += str;
});
$("#output").append(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="output" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Game</th>
    <th>Next Jackpot</th>
    <th>Next drawing</th>
    <th>Winning Numbers</th>
    <th>Game Played Date</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Iceman , So I was on the right track. That make me fill great. Thanks again and have a blessed and profitable day. Jeremy C.

Comment: @JeremyCummings thank you. glad it helped.